# Why is the Riemann Surface of $\sqrt{z}$ not just $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

In Chapter 6 of Silverman's "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves," he introduces elliptic functions by first attempting to integrate the invariant differential of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ $$\omega=dx/y=dx/\sqrt{x(x-1)(x-\lambda)}.$$ But we have path-independence issues, so we need to make some branch cuts. If we cut out a line from 0 to $\infty$ and a line from 1 to $\lambda$, then this square root is single-valued and integrating the differential on this subset is path-independent. We form the Riemann surface of this function by taking two copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ with the indicated slits and gluing them together. This surface is readily seen to be a torus.

So finally we arrive to my question in the title. If we follow the same procedure with the function $\sqrt{z}$, we make the Riemann surface by cutting a line $0$ to $\infty$ in our two copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and then gluing them together. This surface is readily seen to be just another copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

But the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z}$ is *not* $\mathbb{P}^1$. So what is going wrong with the above construction? The best I can surmise is that I'm constructing the Riemann surface for the function $\sqrt{z}$ whose domain is $\mathbb{P}^1$, rather than the function $\sqrt{z}$ whose domain is $\mathbb{C}$.

Any explanation would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is your definition of the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z}$ ?

Comment: I would say a surface on which one can define $\sqrt{z}$ homolomorphically. Usually we would take two copies of $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$ and glue them together along the slit.

Comment: The Riemann surface of $f(z)=z^{1/2}$ is $\{ (z,\pm z^{1/2})\in \Bbb{C}^2, z\in \Bbb{C}^*\}$. The result is biholomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^*$ ie. $\Bbb{P}^1$ minus two points.

Comment: Right. But mimicking the construction in the post above to see that the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{x(x-1)(x-\lambda)}$ is a torus leads me to believe that the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z}$ is a sphere. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The Riemann surface of $\sqrt{x(x-1)(x-\lambda)}$ is a projective elliptic curve minus $4$ points ($\infty=[0:1:0], [0:0:1],[1:0:1],[\lambda:0:1]$) , the projective curve is biholomorphic to a complex torus $\Bbb{C/(w_1Z+w_2 Z})$ obtained by integrating the non-vanishing holomorphic 1-form.

Comment: So if I take two copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$  with slits from 0 to $\infty$ and glue them together along these slits, the resulting surface will be the the Riemann surface for $\sqrt{z}$? My confusion arises because this is how I thought the Riemann surface for this function should be constructed, but this surface looks like a sphere to me

Comment: No. 1) make your gluing construction precise. 2) I have shown above how the Riemann surface of your functions are constructed. In general it is $\{ (z,f_\gamma(z),f_\gamma'(z),\ldots,f^{(k)}_\gamma(z))\}$ where the $f_\gamma$ are all the analytic continuations of $f$ and $z$ is restricted to be in a domain where $f_\gamma$ is analytic. When $f$ is algebraic we can add a few missing points to get a compact Riemann surface.

Comment: Okay. One last question: Why does this (apparently imprecise) construction work for $\sqrt{z(z-1)(z-\lambda)}$ then? Meaning, if we glue together two copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ along slits from 0 to $\infty$ and from 1 to $\lambda$, this space is readily seen to be a torus, which as you say, *is* the correct Riemann surface for this function (at least it's biholomorphic to it). Thank you for your comments by the way.